# Why are tagged expressions not found in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, regex, replace, ssms

I understand from my reading that curly brackets denote tagged expression in a "find" in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) with "use regular expressions" toggled on.  And that backslash n is a placeholder for that matched text in replace.  Even before I get to the replace I cannot get the find to work.  For instance with this text:

> this that

and this "find" regex pattern:

`{[a-z]*}`

I get "the following specified text was not found".  If I remove the curly brackets the find gets a hit on each of those two words as expected.  What am I doing wrong?  This is SSMS v18.5.

Comment: Braces (`{}`) aren't a special character in the REGEX pattern matching. The expression `{[a-z]*}` would match a set of braces that have 0 or more alpha only characters between them. For example `{this}` and `{that}` and `{}`: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mVV3YW/2)

Comment: However, some regex flavors are picky, try `\{[A-Za-z]*\}`

Comment: Thank you both.  While I've phrased the problem in terms of the find, ultimately my need is for a functioning find-replace.  Without the full nitty gritty of my particular need, suppose I wanted to end up with  " that this " starting with " this that ".

Comment: I understood my replace clause could be " \2 \1 " with the braces enclosing the items matching \n counting 1-based from left to right.  I was led to use braces by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-ver15 (search for "tagged").  I tried round brackets in case the documentation was out of date but that doesn't work when I try to replace \2\1.

Comment: @Larnu The brackets _were_ special RegEx syntax in older versions of SSMS. They allowed for the match to be used in replacements as `\1`, `\2`, etc where as parenthesis also did grouping but did not work with `\number` replacement patterns. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use an obsolete syntax (i.e. "tagged expressions") that went away with the older builds of SSMS. I'm not sure when it switched over, but I have a test system with SQL Server 2008 R2 on it, along with the version of SSMS that came with it, and it uses the old style SSMS Regular Expression syntax (which I think is proprietary as I haven't ever seen it used anywhere else).

SSMS now uses .NET Regular Expressions and its syntax. You can tell which type you have by making sure that the cursor is in the query editor and hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. If the search box (attached to the upper, right-hand corner of the query editor) pops up (and the "Find" input field is *not* labeled), then you are using a modern version of SSMS along with .NET Regular Expressions. If, instead, a "Find and Replace" window pops up (and the input field is labeled as "Find what:"), then you are using an older version of SSMS along with its "special" version of Regular Expressions.

### Example

Starting with:

```
this that


one two three four five
```

1. Using (older syntax — tagged expressions):

   **Find what:** `{[a-z]+} {[a-z]+}`
   **Replace with:** `~\2~\1~`

   results in:

   ```
   ~that~this~


   ~two~one~ ~four~three~ five
   ```
2. For newer versions of SSMS, using (newer syntax — capture groups):

   **Find:** `([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)`
   **Replace:** `~$2~$1~`

   with the same starting text produces the exact same result.

### Info

In the older versions, there is an arrow button to the right of the "Find" / "Replace" fields that will display a quick list of commonly used syntax, the bottom option being a link to the documentation.

In the newer versions, the "Find" and "Replace" (technically they are actually "Quick Find" and "Quick Replace") dialog does not have any help button. *However*, if you go to the "Edit" menu, then go to "Find and Replace   ➧", you will see options for "Find in Files" and "Replace in Files". These two options will open a window that is basically the "Find and Replace" window from the older versions, slightly updated, though still titled as "Find and Replace". This "Find and Replace" window has the help buttons on the right of the "Find" and "Replace" fields, both of which have an option for "Regular Expression Help" which takes you to the correct RegEx documentation (linked below).

- [Older SSMS RegEx documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions)
- [Newer SSMS/Visual Studio RegEx documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio)